Android - Error taking picture with react-native-camera: E_TAKE_PICTURE_FAILED
I'm encountering an issue when trying to take a picture using the react-native-camera library in my React Native app. The takePicture function fails with the following error:

I'm using the following code to take a picture:
const takePicture = async () => {
    if (camera) {
      try {
        await camera.resumePreview(); 
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100)); 
        const data = await camera.takePictureAsync();
        console.log('Picture taken', data);

        const image = {
          localPath: data.uri,
          imageType: vehicleImageIndex,
        };
        const updatedPictures = [...cameraPictures];
        updatedPictures[vehicleImageIndex] = image;
        setCameraPictures(updatedPictures);

        setVehicleImageIndex(prevIndex => prevIndex + 1); 

      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error taking picture: ', error);
      }
    } else {
      console.log('Camera not ready');
    }
};

I've tried the following to resolve the issue but to no avail:

Checked camera permissions in AndroidManifest.xml
Verified the camera object is properly initialized
Added a delay before calling takePictureAsync()

Has anyone faced a similar issue or has any idea how to fix this? Any help would be appreciated.
Environment:

React Native version: "0.71.15",
react-native-camera version: "^4.2.1"


https://react-native-camera.github.io/react-native-camera/docs/installation.html
proceed with this installation procedure.

You may eventually receive this error as a result of an improper installation procedure or a package that isn't connected to your project.

Thanks @PratikPrakashBindage, I have followed the installation. But the issue still persists for Android, IOS works fine

Insert the following lines in android/app/build.gradle:
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general' // <--- insert this line
  }
}

Additional information in case of problems
Make sure you use JDK >= 1.7 and your buildToolsVersion >= 25.0.2
Make sure you have jitpack added in android/build.gradle
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}

this lib is no longer maintained you can use react-native-image-crop-picker or
react-native-vision-camera instead of it
Hope it will help you. see the documentation

Yes i have that line in my code.
But still the issue persists

You can check the edited answer

https://github.com/react-native-camera/react-native-camera/blob/master/docs/installation.md#requirements

Thanks for sharing!
I have plans for migration to react-native-vision camera, but right now i want to resolve with current react-native-camera-library.
I followed the installation guide, but still it is not working. Previously it used to work, with older version of react-native 0.71.8
